# ExtJS loop through form fields that got a specified name

Tags: extjs, loops, field

I'm using ExtJS 3. I have a formPanel with many "cloned" fields and I gave every field the name "price[]". After submit I would like to loop through every field that has the name "price[]" and get their values one at a time to be checked against something in the database.

Note: there are other fields in this form so that's why I need to specify witch items to get from it, by name. I know how to submit the form, I just need to loop through those field and get their values.

How can I do this ?

Thank you!

Comment: After submit meaning when you are in your server context (PHP, J2EE, RoR, etc.)? Or when you are still within the context of Javascript?

Comment: I just need to know how to loop and get their values. No help needed on the submit part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find(propName, value)` method of [FormPanel](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.FormPanel). It returns an array of all the matches. The matches will be Ext.form.WhateverField objects, depending on what types of input elements your form has, and not raw DOM elements.

```
var priceFields = myFormPanel.find('name', 'price[]');
```

Answer (score 0):

The BasicForm object has a property **items**: it is a mixed collection.  You may iterate over the collection.

[ExtJS forum](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=80008)

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to specify that those are not the only fields from the form. I got many other fields so I need to grab those by the name.

Comment: Could you iterate over all fields, check the name, and ignore those that are not interesting?

Comment: If not, then I suggest you query your form using a CSS selector.